# Compromising Python if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I have to work with a bunch of `if` statement in one code. They are all the same with slight changes. Is there any way how I can compromise all this code and make it more elegant and shorter ?

Code below:

```
if con_name == 'coh':
    coh = my_coherence(n_freqs, Rxy_mean, Rxx_mean, Ryy_mean)
    coh_surro = my_coherence(n_freqs, Rxy_s_mean, Rxx_s_mean, Ryy_s_mean)
    return coh, coh_surro, freqs, freqs_surro

if con_name == 'imcoh':
    imcoh = my_imcoh(n_freqs, Rxy_mean, Rxx_mean, Ryy_mean)
    imcoh_surro = my_imcoh(n_freqs, Rxy_s_mean, Rxx_s_mean, Ryy_s_mean)
    return imcoh, imcoh_surro, freqs, freqs_surro

if con_name == 'cohy':
    cohy = my_cohy(n_freqs, Rxy_mean, Rxx_mean, Ryy_mean)
    cohy_surro = my_cohy(n_freqs, Rxy_s_mean, Rxx_s_mean, Ryy_s_mean)
    return cohy, cohy_surro, freqs, freqs_surro

if con_name == 'plv':
    plv = my_plv(n_freqs, Rxy, Rxy_mean)
    plv_surro = my_plv(n_freqs, Rxy_s, Rxy_s_mean)
    return plv, plv_surro, freqs, freqs_surro

if con_name == 'pli':
    pli = my_pli(n_freqs, Rxy, Rxy_mean)
    pli_surro = my_pli(n_freqs, Rxy_s, Rxy_s_mean)
    return pli, pli_surro, freqs, freqs_surro

if con_name == 'wpli':
    wpli = my_wpli(n_freqs, Rxy, Rxy_mean)
    wpli_surro = my_wpli(n_freqs, Rxy_s, Rxy_s_mean)
    return wpli, wpli_surro, freqs, freqs_surro
```

I am sorry if this is to easy, but I tried and tried and can't figure out a way.

Comment: FIrst of all you could use elif rather than just if

Comment: `elif` is useless since there is a `return` in all statements.

Comment: @Hacketo yep didn't see that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r = {
    'coh':   lambda: (my_coherence(n_freqs, Rxy_mean, Rxx_mean, Ryy_mean), my_coherence(n_freqs, Rxy_s_mean, Rxx_s_mean, Ryy_s_mean), freqs, freqs_surro),
    'imcoh': lambda: (my_imcoh(n_freqs, Rxy_mean, Rxx_mean, Ryy_mean), my_imcoh(n_freqs, Rxy_s_mean, Rxx_s_mean, Ryy_s_mean), freqs, freqs_surro),
    'cohy':  lambda: (my_cohy(n_freqs, Rxy_mean, Rxx_mean, Ryy_mean), my_cohy(n_freqs, Rxy_s_mean, Rxx_s_mean, Ryy_s_mean), freqs, freqs_surro),
    'plv':   lambda: (my_plv(n_freqs, Rxy, Rxy_mean), my_plv(n_freqs, Rxy_s, Rxy_s_mean), freqs, freqs_surro),
    'pli':   lambda: (my_pli(n_freqs, Rxy, Rxy_mean), my_pli(n_freqs, Rxy_s, Rxy_s_mean), freqs, freqs_surro),
    'wpli':  lambda: (my_wpli(n_freqs, Rxy, Rxy_mean), my_wpli(n_freqs, Rxy_s, Rxy_s_mean), freqs, freqs_surro),
    }
return r[con_name]()
```

You can further avoid repetitions, for example last two items are repeated for each case:

```
r = {
    'coh':   lambda: (my_coherence(n_freqs, Rxy_mean, Rxx_mean, Ryy_mean), my_coherence(n_freqs, Rxy_s_mean, Rxx_s_mean, Ryy_s_mean)),
    'imcoh': lambda: (my_imcoh(n_freqs, Rxy_mean, Rxx_mean, Ryy_mean), my_imcoh(n_freqs, Rxy_s_mean, Rxx_s_mean, Ryy_s_mean)),
    'cohy':  lambda: (my_cohy(n_freqs, Rxy_mean, Rxx_mean, Ryy_mean), my_cohy(n_freqs, Rxy_s_mean, Rxx_s_mean, Ryy_s_mean)),
    'plv':   lambda: (my_plv(n_freqs, Rxy, Rxy_mean), my_plv(n_freqs, Rxy_s, Rxy_s_mean)),
    'pli':   lambda: (my_pli(n_freqs, Rxy, Rxy_mean), my_pli(n_freqs, Rxy_s, Rxy_s_mean)),
    'wpli':  lambda: (my_wpli(n_freqs, Rxy, Rxy_mean), my_wpli(n_freqs, Rxy_s, Rxy_s_mean)),
    }
return r[con_name]() + (freqs, freqs_surro)
```

Comment: I was about to write a similar answer, but I believe it's better to pass arguments to `lambda`s for them to be proper high-order functions, e.g. the call would look like `r[con_name](...arguments for inner functions...)`

Comment: @ mescalinum: Thanks. It's a nice approach. I corrected your tiny mistakes and it works fine.

Answer (score 5):

Without reflection

```
func, flag = {
    "coh": (my_coherence, True),
    "imcoh": (my_imcoh, True)
    "cohy": (my_cohy, True),
    "ply": (my_plv, False),
    "pli": (my_pli, False),
    "wpli": (my_wpli, False)
}[con_name]

args = (n_freqs, Rxy_mean, Rxx_mean, Ryy_mean) if flag else (n_freqs, Rxy, Rxy_mean)
surro_args = (n_freqs, Rxy_s_mean, Rxx_s_mean, Ryy_s_mean) if flag else (n_freqs, Rxy_s Rxy_s_mean)

val = func(*args)
surro = func(*surro_args)
return val, surro, freqs, freqs_surro
```

OR This is also possible

```
...
args = (Rxy_mean, Rxx_mean, Ryy_mean) if flag else (Rxy, Rxy_mean)
surro_args = (Rxy_s_mean, Rxx_s_mean, Ryy_s_mean) if flag else (Rxy_s Rxy_s_mean)

val = func(n_freqs, *args)
surro = func(n_freqs *surro_args)
...
```

Maybe there is a cool name for `flag` for classifying those functions. Use it instead.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a dictionary. Something like:

```
functions = {'coh':my_coherence,'imcoh':my_imcoh....}
```

Which would be called like this:

```
functions[con_name](n_freqs, Rxy_s_mean, Rxx_s_mean, Ryy_s_mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Reflection](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/reflection.html). I would create a method, which would be responsible for calling the given methods. I would pass the two method names in each case and the parameters. Based on the method param names you could call each time the right function and return what is needed. And in the code chunk you have shown I would call the method, passing the two method names and the parameters.